# Handlebars/Express/Nodejs Get the selected dropdown list item and value after POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

I have form which contains a basic input and a dropdown menu item. I wrote this to be dynamic (I get data for the dropdown menu from DB). Here is my form

```
<form action="/get_book" method="POST" id="tableform">
    <div>
    <label for="personName">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="personName" pattern="[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+" name="personName">
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="bookIsbnNumber">ISBN Number:</label>
    {{#if konyvISBN}}
    <select class="bookIsbnNumber" name="bookIsbnNumber">
         {{#each konyvISBN}}
    <option value={{ISBN}}>{{ISBN}}</option>
         {{/each}}
    </select>
    {{else}}
       <p class="message">No requests to show</p>
    {{/if}}
    </div>    
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="getBook">Get the book</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

My problem is, that when the form is submitted on /get_book I want to get the book rented person's name and the selected ID. With the request.fields.personName I got the name correctly, but I can't get the selected ISBN number even with body-parser. Can somebody write the form of getting the selected item and its value please, because I searched a lot for it in SO, but I have not found anything useful. All helps are appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me that you should be providing your API-side `/get_book` handler here.

Comment: I found the problems it was with the eformidable which I used for files requests. If i delte it works fine, but now I'm looking for something for file accessing (i have another form with file upload) because express-fileupload works with image uploading good, but ruins my other fields. Do you have any idea?